# Conditional Formatting blank cells -VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to highlight a cell in column B if it is less than value in column F. For example if cell B2 is 10 and F2 is 20, B2 should be red. However in column B there are blank cells i do not want these highlighted. For example B6 is blank but F6 is 10. In my code B6 become red as well.

Also how would i highlight a cell in the same row that is already highlighted. For example, if B2 is highlighted, highlight F2.

My code is below:

```
Sub threecf()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
    Set rg = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

    'clear any existing conditional formatting
    rg.FormatConditions.Delete

    'define the rule for each conditional format
    Set cond1 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, "=f2")
    Set cond2 = rg.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=isempty(f2)")

    'define the format applied for each conditional format
    With cond1
      .Interior.Color = vbRed
      .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With

    With cond2
      .Interior.Color = vbWhite
      .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA and not Excel Formula?

Comment: If your ranges are not too big, maybe you should format your cells directly with VBA commands and not using conditional formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, use formulas. No need to use VBA

**Easiest Way (Recommended Way)**

*I recommend this way because it takes into account new rows that are being added.*

1. Select Col B
2. Select Home Tab | Conditional formatting | New Rule | Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. Enter the formula `=AND(B1<F1,B1<>"")`
4. Select Format | Fill Tab
5. Set Fill color to red :)

**Customized Way**

1. Manually select cells B2 to last row in col B
2. Select Home Tab | Conditional formatting | New Rule | Use a formula to determine which cells to format
3. Enter the formula `=AND(B2<F2,B2<>"")`
4. Select Format | Fill Tab
5. Set Fill color to red :)

**VBA Way**

If you still want VBA then try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("B2:B" & lRow)
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(B2<F2,B2<>"""")"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to conditional formatting --> New Rule --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format --> Paste This: `=IF(AND(B2<F2,B2<>"") = TRUE,1,0)`

For the F column: `=IF(AND(F2>B2,F2<>"") = TRUE,1,0)`

Comment: No need to use `IF()`. Also you forgot to mention that user need to select the relevant column :)  Simplest way would be to select Col B and `Conditional formatting --> New Rule --> Use a formula  =AND(B1<F1,B1<>"")` and set the fill color to red :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a VBA solution, try it without conditional formatting:

```
Sub StackOverflow()
    Dim x As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stack")
        For x = 1 To .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            If .Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" And .Cells(x, 2).Value < .Cells(x, 6).Value Then
                .Cells(x, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
                .Cells(x, 6).Interior.Color = vbRed
                .Cells(x, 2).Font.Color = vbWhite
                .Cells(x, 6).Font.Color = vbWhite
            Else
                .Cells(x, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                .Cells(x, 6).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                .Cells(x, 2).Font.Color = vbBlack
                .Cells(x, 6).Font.Color = vbBlack
            End If
        Next x
    End With
End Sub
```

Adapt the code to your needs (change the macro name, spreadsheet address and colors if you want).

Comment: Very bad suggestion/alternative in my opinion :(

Comment: @Siddharth Rout, may I ask why?

Comment: Sure. let me post a solution first and then I will reply to your cmment

Comment: Because of 2 reasons `1` User is looking to solve a conditionl formatting problem. Instead of solving his query you are tryig to avoid the topic. `2` Manually coloring cells is not practical. if user changes the value of the cell then he or she needs to run the code again and again. Conditional formatting prevent that scenario :)

Comment: sorry nothing prsonal here :)

Comment: Not sure if I agree with you... `1` We see alternative suggestions/solutions all the time on this matter (you did that yourself). That's simply a point of view. `2` OP could always call this routine on the `worksheet.change` event when he messes around with that specific cells... But, of course, I respect your opinion.

Comment: Alternative should only be given if it is beneficial :) Introducing a worksheet change for such a small thing is an overkill in my opinion :)

Comment: That's ok. We're good... The greatest thing on this issue is that OP's getting a lot of solutions... He/She only have to pick one...

Comment: Thanks Mate. I like your Spirit! :)